# Why does this empty while loop cause lag?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame constructor, called from Main.java (The class for the JFrame is Page1.java)

```
movieSelection p1 = new movieSelection();
this.add(p1);
this.pack();
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setVisible(true);
```

movieChoose is a class that extends JPanel , and is a subclass of Page1. It consists of a constructor that adds a JTextField and a JButton with an ActionListener.

The end result looks like this [image]

At the end of Page1.java's constructor, if I add `while(true) {};` or just `while(true);` the end result is this: [image]  along with a whole lot of lag.

According to Activity Monitor, this is how much is space the program is taking up:

20 threads
261 ports
Nearly 200% of the CPU

How can this empty while loop: 
 a) Mess up the JPanel thats already been added to the frame, and 
 b) Produce a whole lot of lag?

Why does a loop that's doing nothing do something?

Comment: What other result would you expect from adding an infinite loop to your application?

Comment: Since the loop **never** ends, there's no way your program can process the other sentences after the infinite loop you declared (at least that this loop is inside a thread).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza consider that as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all gui stuff in swing is executed in the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

if you block this thread with heavy task

for example

```
while(true){

 };
```

then gui get freeze until finish, but code never ends so never finish so never can render gui.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just doing nothing. It's looping. When you say 'a whole lot of lag,' I assume you mean that the app hangs completely? I'd be surprised if it does anything once it hits that while().

Answer (score 0):

Because that loop never stops checking if the value is true...
That's why it's called an infinite loop. Every cycle is used to check if it should stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

An empty (and infinite) loop actually does a lot - it is like a sheet of paper telling you to turn a page, and on the back it says the same.

So never ever do an empty loop in any computer language.

What you could do is something like

```
 while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
 }
```

That's better, because now you let your main thread run but tell the JVM "okay, I'm not going to do something for 100 ms, so do something else if you need to".

But still you miss an important thing - some exit condition.

And why do you need an endless loop at all? In a normal swing application there is no need to keep the main thread running, it is sufficient that a JFrame is open. You can see some example code at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: *An empty loop actually does a lot* you mean an **infinite** loop, an **empty** loop that has a defined end condition will do nothing but just waste time and possibly memory.

Comment: while (System.currentTimeMillis()==-1) {} is finite and empty and will have the same effect for some billion years. The most destructive thing in the question is the empty body, but I agree that it is more precise to call it empty and infinite, changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The lag is likely being caused because the loop is being, theoretically, executed an infinite amount of times. Maybe you could try pausing the thread, which gives the CPU some time to breathe:

```
Thread.sleep(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Very old so probably not reading but THANK YOU!  Answered a most troublesome question.  (I was working with a dual-core processor before, now switched to a single and my empty while {} statements just stopped working!)